# Select top 1 Name from Group

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working in MS Access and need SQL to return the top 1 result from a group.

Data looks like this:

```
ID     Name
1      All Users
2      All Users
3      All Users
4      Some Users
5      Some Users
6      Some Users
```

My results I need are:

```
ID     Name
1      All Users
4      Some Users
```

Table name is `tblGroup`.

Comment: Top 1 result from what group?

Comment: too late to say **SO is not a free code service!** :(

Answer (score 1):

This returns the result set you want.  Is it what you intend?

```
select min(id) as id, name
from tblGroup
group by name;
```

Comment: _name_ needs wrapping: _[name]_.

Comment: Yes exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!